# delete source files spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a spring integration file that using inbound adapter reads some files from local directory and then stores it in couchdb. I would want to delete it in the end. In my properties file , I used delete.source.files=true. However, this doesnt seem to work. I read in other stackflow questions that i could use ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice. I used it with my inboundchanneladapter, but it does not work.

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesInput" expression= "headers['file_originalFile'].delete()?null:null"
        directory="file:${incoming.path}/${tw.instance}" queue-size="8"
        filename-pattern="*.json" prevent-duplicates="true" channel="filesIn"  >
        <int:poller id="poller" fixed-rate="${file.read.interval.millis}"
            task-executor="pollerExecutor" />
    </file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

any other way of deleting it?  what is wrong with the expression. I'm new to spring integration. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is no `expression` option on the `<file:inbound-channel-adapter>`. Another case that there is really no any options for that component to delete files. Since this component is fully based on the `java.io.File` objects there is no reason to introduce any delete functionality since the simple `File.delete()` is enough in any downstream place.

Right, `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` can be used on the matter but as a `<request-handler-advice-chain>` on the `<service-activator>` for that couchdb operation. Its `onSuccessExpression` option can be use to perform `File.delete()`.

Comment: My problem is there's three outbound-channel-adapter
<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="archiveFileWriter"
  channel="filesIn"
  directory-expression="'${archive.path}/${tw.instance}/' + @dirNameGenerator.yearMonthDayHour()"
  delete-source-files="${delete.source.files}" />

<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="errorFileWriter"
  channel="stringFailureChannel" directory-expression="'${error.path}/' + @dirNameGenerator.yearMonthDay()"
  filename-generator-expression="'ERR-talkwalker-' + T(java.lang.System).currentTimeMillis() + '.json'"
  delete-source-files="${delete.source.files}" />

Comment: <int:outbound-channel-adapter ref="couchDbOutbound" channel="outputToCouch"/>
Where do i use the <request-handler-advice-chain>?